# iOS 11, Unity3d random startup crash

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, crash, startup, ios11

There are 2 unity games developed by different developers (one 2D and another 3D).

They work fine while started in XCode and work fine on iOS 10.

But when downloaded from Appstore to iOS 10 and iOS got upgraded to iOS 11 then app start randomly crash.

Usually it crashes 3 times then start working. On some devices it does not crash at all or other devices it randomly crashes when games start.

Crashlogs have 2 types of errors:

**Error 1**

```
Date/Time:           2017-09-26 09:52:53.6413 -0400
Launch Time:         2017-09-26 09:52:50.4289 -0400
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.0 (15A372)
Baseband Version:    6.17.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Subtype: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000105000000
VM Region Info: 0x105000000 is in 0x105000000-0x1069c4000;  bytes after start: 0  bytes before end: 27017215
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      MALLOC_SMALL           0000000104800000-0000000105000000 [ 8192K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
--->  mapped file            0000000105000000-00000001069c4000 [ 25.8M] r--/r-- SM=ALI  
      MALLOC_LARGE           00000001069c4000-00000001069c8000 [   16K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  

Termination Signal: Bus error: 10
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xa
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0
```

**Error 2**

```
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.0 (15A372)
Baseband Version:    6.17.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, process-exit watchdog transgression: bundleid exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 5.00 seconds |  | Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 9.360 (user 9.360, system 0.000), 94% CPU | Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 2.920, 29% CPU |
Triggered by Thread:  0
```

Also I noticed that Tumblr app similarly crashed 3 times on startup after iOS 11 Beta -> iOS 11 release update.

Unity3D 5.5 was used to develop these 2 games.

Comment: Are you suing any network code such as TCP/UPD or  http request in your program?

Comment: Game has a lot of networking code including ad networks, analytics, unity services. It definitely use network API. It crashes instantly on startup even before "loading logo" appears not sure if it does any networking code in first second.

Comment: Sorry I can't help. By doing a little search, the problem seems to occur when you do network stuff in the main thread when game starts causing the main thread to block. You need to make a copy of your project then start removing plugins until you find which one is causing this problem.

Comment: Interesting. So iOS 11 kills apps that do networking on main thread. One of crashes called `nanosleep -> __semwait_signal` on main thread. may be sleep is not allowed.

Comment: I only searched the second error which  is *"Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d"*. Google it and read more about it

Comment: I have not searched by 0x8badf00d Code. Thank You

Comment: How did you resolve this problem finally? I got the same one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading to Unity 2017.1 p3 (patch 3) from Unity3D 5.5 fixed most bugs.
We had few bugs in Unity 2017.1 f1 (f3)